# How do I clear the output screen in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a text based rpg in python 3 and the output window gets very cluttered cluttered. I was wondering if there was a way to clear the screen automatically from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

You can  use `os.system('clear')` if you are on linux.